# In a layered architecture using Entity Framework, should I return POCO classes from the BLL? (Architecture guidance needed)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, mvvm, poco

I've been reading too much probably and am suffering from some information overload. So I would appreciate some explicit guidance.

From what I've gathered, I can use VS2010's T4 template thingy to generate POCO classes that aren't tied directly to the EF. I would place these in their own project while my DAL would have an ObjectContext-derived class, right?

Once I have these classes, is it acceptable practice to use them in the UI layer? That is, say one of the generated classes is `BookInfo` that holds stuff about books for a public library (Title, edition, pages, summary etc.).

My BLL would contain a class `BooksBLL` for example like so:

```
public class BooksBLL
{
    ObjectContext _context;

    public void AddBook(BookInfo book) { ... }
    public void DeleteBook(int bookID) { ... }
    public void UpdateBook(int bookID, BookInfo newBook) { ... }

    //Advanced search taking possibly all fields into consideration
    public List<BookInfo> ResolveSearch(Func<BookInfo, bool> filter) { ... }

    //etc...
}
```

So, my ViewModels in my MVVM UI app will be communicating with the above BLL class and exchanging BookInfo instances. Is that okay?

Furthermore, MVVM posts on the Web suggest implementing `IDataErrorInfo` for validation purposes. Is it okay if I implement said interface on the generated POCO class? I see from samples that those generated POCO classes contain all virtual properties and stuf and I hope adding my own logic would be okay?

If it makes any difference, at present, my app does not use WCF (or any networking stuff).

Also, if you see something terribly wrong with the way I'm trying to build my BLL, please feel free to offer help in that area too.

**Update (Additional info as requested):**

I'm trying to create a library automation application. It is **not** network based at present.

I am thinking about having layers as follows:

- A project consisting of generated POCO classes (BookInfo, Author, Member, Publisher,  Contact etc.)
- A project with the ObjectContext-derived class (DAL?)
- A Business Logic Layer with classes like the one I mentioned above (BooksBLL, AuthorsBLL etc)
- A WPF UI layer using the MVVM pattern. (Hence my sub-question about IDataErrorInfo implementation).

So I'm wondering about stuff like using an instance of `BooksBLL` in a ViewModel class, calling `ResolveSearch()` on it to obtain a `List<BookInfo>` and presenting it... that is, using the POCO classes everywhere.

Or should I have additional classes that mirror the POCO classes exposed from my BLL?

If any more detail is needed, please ask.

Comment: First think you should know is that there is no "right" answer to this question - instead there are many solutions that work differently.  It isn't easy to pick the one that fits your needs perfectly.  This is why you are getting information overload.  To give the "right" answer, we will need a little more info about the app you are building.

Comment: @Mark: I can see how architecture guidance would be subjective, but how about the specific questions, ie. using POCO classes in UI layer and implementing IDataErrorInfo on POCO classes? In any case, I'll try to add more detail about my project.

Comment: @ForeverLearn: If you implement IDataErrorInfo, your classes are no longer POCOs.  The whole idea of POCOs is that they don't contain code pertaining to outside concerns.  Thus, if you use IDataErrorInfo to facilitate form validation, you're no longer dealing in POCOs.  My understanding in MVVM is that the "Model" is the application model, not the domain model, so your domain POCOs wouldn't be bound to your UI controls.  I'm not familiar with the examples you're talking about, but I surely hope it is OK to add your own logic to your business logic classes, else they would be pretty pointless.

Comment: @CodeMonkey1: Oh... <_>. So does that mean that I need to make a whole new set of almost equivalent classes in my BLL? (BookInfoBLL, AuthorBLL etc..)?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject whatsover but I am almost positive there should be no problem with it. I think that is one of the reasons behind EFCodeFirst as well (Have a look at that if you have not already because it should help you alot)

Comment: @ForeverLearn: Posted an answer because I kept running out of characters in comments.

Comment: @CodeMonkey1: I disagree with your opinion on `IDataErrorInfo`. This interface is a simple contract from `System.ComponentModel` to report a model object state. It has nothing directly to do with UI although it is mainly used in this context. If you refuse to implement it on the POCO classes you have to pay the price of additional complexity. You cannot justify a higher price only by design and pattern purism (unless perhaps you write code as an artist).

Comment: @Slauma: I didn't say he shouldn't do it, only that it breaks the idea of a POCO. The issue on IDataErrorInfo is fuzzy, since it is being implemented for the sole purpose of interacting with a specific UI technology, but I might agree with you that it could still be called a POCO.  However, it still mixes UI concerns with business concerns, which isn't always bad but doesn't mesh with the goal of creating a layered architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't *need* to do anything in particular... as Mark said, there is no "right" answer.  However, if your application is simple enough that you would simply be duplicating your classes (e.g. BookInfoUI & BookInfoBLL), then I'd recommend just using the business classes.  The extra layer wouldn't serve a purpose, and so it shouldn't exist.  Eric Evans in DDD even recommends putting all your logic in the UI layer if you app is simple and has very little business logic.

To make the distinction, the application layer should have classes that model what happens within the application, and the domain layer should have classes that model what happens in the domain.  For example, if you have a search page, your UI layer might retrieve a list of BookSearchResult objects from a BookSearchService in the application layer, which would use the domain to pull a list of BookInfo.

Comment: Your example was actually what led me to this question in the first palace. I was thinking that my 'BookSearchResult' class was really no different from a regular BookInfo class... so what was the point of having a new class and wondered if I could directly use the BookInfo class in my ViewModel (as a generated POCO).

Comment: Well, I'd assume BookInfo contains properties for Title, Author, Publisher, and that the latter two of those are complex types with their own sets of properties. But, does BookSearchResult really care about all the details, or does it perhaps just need BookTitle, AuthorName, PublisherName?  This is a trivial example, but you can start to see how BookSearchResult models exactly what we need for the search result without regard for what may or may not be present in our business layer's Book object.

Comment: I guess you could be right. I have ALL the BookInfo related stuff displayed, but only names of authors and name of publisher. And perhaps AuthorID as well, to enable clicking on an author name and opening a related view displaying Author details. BUT, for say, AddBook(), I would still have to pass in a mirror image of the original BookInfo... except with IDataErrorInfo implemented on it. Hmm...

Comment: If you don't foresee later additional complexity, then it sounds like you could get away with just a UI and data access layer, and your entity classes could implement whatever interfaces they need for UI binding and validation.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the follow-up thoughts.

Answer (score 4):

What you're doing is basically the Repository pattern, for which Entity Framework and POCO are a great fit.

> So, my ViewModels in my MVVM UI app will be communicating with the above BLL class and exchanging BookInfo instances. Is that okay?

That's exactly what POCO objects are for; there's no difference between the classes that are generated and how you would write them by hand. It's your ObjectContext that encapsulates all the logic around persisting any changes back to the database, and that's not directly exposed to your UI.

I'm not personally familiar with `IDataErrorInfo` but if right now your entities will only be used in this single app, I don't see any reason not to put it directly in the generated classes. Adding it to the T4 template would be ideal if that's possible, it would save you having to code it by hand for every class if the error messages follow any logical pattern.

> Also, if you see something terribly wrong with the way I'm trying to build my BLL, please feel free to offer help in that area too.

This isn't *terribly wrong* by any means, but if you plan to write unit tests against your BLL (which I would recommend), you will want to change your `ObjectContext` member to `IObjectContext`. That way you can substitute any class implementing the `IObjectContext` interface at runtime (such as your *actual* `ObjectContext`), which will allow you to do testing against an in-memory (i.e. mocked) context and not have to hit the database.

Similarly, think about replacing your `List<BookInfo>` with an interface of some kind such as `IList<BookInfo>` or `IBindingList<BookInfo>` or the lowest common denominator `IEnumerable<BookInfo>`. That way you're not tied directly to the specific class `List<T>` and if your needs change over time, which tends to happen, it will reduce the refactoring necessary to replace your `List<BookInfo>` with something else, assuming whatever you're replacing it with implements the interface you've chosen.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'll chew on them for a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Answers to your questions may depend on the size and complexity of your application. So I am afraid there will be valid arguments to answer your questions with Yes and No as well.

Personally I will answer your two main questions both with Yes:

**Is it acceptable practice to use POCO (Domain) classes in the UI layer?**

I guess with "UI layer" you don't actually mean the View part of the MVVM pattern but the ViewModels. (Most MVVM specialists would argue against letting a View directly reference the Model at all, I believe.)

It is not unusual to wrap a POCO from your Domain project as a property into a ViewModel and to bind this wrapped POCO directly to the View. The big Pro is: It's easy. You don't need additional ViewModel classes or replicated properties in a ViewModel and then copy those properties between the objects.

However, if you are using WPF you must take into account that the binding engine will directly write into your POCO properties if you bind them to a View. This might not always be what you want, especially if you are working with attached and change-tracked entities in a WPF form. You have to think about cancellation scenarios or how you restore properties after a cancellation which have been changed by the binding engine.

In my current project I am working with detached entities: I load the POCO from the data layer, detach it from context, dispose the context and then work with that copy in the ViewModel and bind it to the View. Updating in the data layer happens by creating a new context, loading the original entity from the DB by ID and then updating the properties from the changed POCO which was bound to the View. So the problem of unwished changes of an attached entity disappears with this approach. But there are also downsides to work with detached entites (updating is more complex for instance).

**Is it okay if I implement the `IDataErrorInfo` interface on the generated POCO class?**

If you bind your POCO entities to a View (through a wrapping ViewModel) it is not only OK but you even *must* implement `IDataErrorInfo` on the POCO class if you want to leverage the built-in property validation of the WPF binding engine. Although this interface is mainly used together with UI technologies it is part of `System.ComponentModel` namespace and therefore not directly tied to any UI namespaces. Basically `IDataErrorInfo` is only a simple contract which supports reporting of the object's state which also might be useful outside of a UI context.

The same is true for the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface which you also would need to implement on your POCO classes if you bind them directly to a View.

I often see opinions which would disagree with me for several architectural reasons. But none of those opinions argue that another approach is easier. If you strictly would want to avoid to have POCO model classes in your ViewModel layer, you need to add another mapping layer with additional complexity and programming and maintenance effort. So I would vote: Keep it simple as long as you do not have a convincing reason and clear benefit to make your architecture more complex.

Comment: Thanks. A lot of ponderable points, especially the cancellation scenario.